# Wrong controller function getting called

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm building a small HR management system for my company, and am facing a weird issue with GoDaddy hosting. As if the pain that comes with figuring out the `index.php?` part was not enough, now I'm not able to log in as an HR. The error I get is that:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/content/37/11019837/html/hrms/application/controllers/hr.php on line 58

Now the line it refers to is part of a file upload function, and goes like this:

```
$path = $this->upload->data()['full_path'];
```

. . . which is simply saving the uploaded file path to $path. BUT, this is part of the uploading function and shouldn't even be accessed while logging in. Once I hit "Log in", the URL says http://www.example.com/hrms/index.php?/hr/dashboard which means the following function will be called:

```
public function dashboard()
    {
        $data['page_title'] = 'HR Area';
        $this->load->view('hr/header.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('hr/navigation.php');
        $this->load->view('hr/footer.php');
    }
```

A parting note: The app is working without hiccups on the local server, so I'm not sure why it's hopping functions on GoDaddy servers. Can someone throw some light?

Comment: did you enable the `query_stsrings`?

Comment: @tomexsans Actually I've found that CI works in AUTO mode also on GoDaddy as long as the index.php? is correctly set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$path = $this->upload->data();
$path1 = $path['full_path'];
```

Comment: That did it! But tell me what was it about. :)

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).